# Run jQuery click event after postback using an update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I have a page that looks like below:

[image: Step 1]

Then the user select any of the add buttons and it expands as below:

[image: step2]

User can then if they wish enter a single value in Feb and press copy, this does the postback using an update panel and updates all the text boxes and updates the total, the problem is that I want the page to stay expanded as below after the postback

[image: step3]

But as the add using a click event in jQuery the box then closes and returns to look like the first picture. I presume I use something like:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "myFunction", "myFunction();", True)
```

The jQuery in question that is fired when the user presses ADD is as follows:

```
            $("#content .step_2 .addtrabox > ul > li .title_1 a.addbtn").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".add_box").slideToggle(300);
        });
```

Comment: what is your jquery code for Copy button? Do you have `e.preventDefault();` for the Copy button click event?

Comment: expended retained with data in it?

Comment: yes I do have e.preventDefault(); before it

Comment: and yes expanded with the data in it